# Why is Bash not recognising my variable as a string?

Tags: string, bash, integer

I've made a bash script. Let's call it "runner.sh". Inside it I'm running omxplayer with some flags.

```
omxplayer $TARGETFOLDER/*.mp4
```

This works fine. Now let's resize and position the video.

```
omxplayer —win "0 0 640 480" $TARGETFOLDER/*.mp4
```

This too works fine. Now let's try to put the "win flag" in a variable. I'm escaping the quote.

```
SizeAndPosition="—win \"0 0 640 480\""
```

Allright, now I'm trying it out.

```
omxplayer $SizeAndPosition $TARGETFOLDER/*.mp4
```

Nope, doesn't work. I get the error *File "0" not found.* Just to be sure, I print the whole command to the screen.

```
echo "omxplayer $SizeAndPosition $TARGETFOLDER/*.mp4"
```

… and I get the output…

```
omxplayer —win "0 0 640 480" /homefolder/*.mp4
```

Why doesn't it recognise my variable as any other string in the command? Can I do something about it?

EDIT: Sorry about the confusion. The question is about SizeAndPosition, why is it not treated as an argument?

Comment: How is `TARGETFOLDER` defined? (side note: You should really put quotes around `$TARGETFOLDER` in `"$TARGETFOLDER"/*.mp4` in case it contains spaces. It that were the problem, it'd break in a different way, though.)

Comment: Not sure if this makes any difference however isn't it supposed to be as follows: `--win "x1 y1 x2 y2"`, notice `--` not `-` in front of `win`?

Comment: I think I'm confused. Is the question why`$TARGETFOLDER` is not expanded or why `$SizeAndPosition` is not treated as two separate arguments?

Comment: @Wintermute while I agree with quoting `$TARGETFOLDER/*.mp4` the error message suggests an issue with `$SizeAndPosition`. At least that's my take on it.

Comment: @user3439894 I was going by the output of the `echo` command. But you're right; `$SizeAndPosition` is not going to be split as expected.

Comment: @Wintermute I've made an edit now, to clear up the confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [storing the command arguments in a variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), use an array:

```
SizeAndPosition=(-win '0 0 640 480')
omxplayer "${SizeAndPosition[@]}" "$TARGETFOLDER"/*.mp4
```

Comment: I don't have omxplayer or Raspberry Pi to test with however the output of `omxplayer -h` (found on the Internet) shows `--win "x1 y1 x2 y2"       Set position of video window` showing the `x1 y1 x2 y2` surrounded by quotes yet in an array what's passed out will be `-win 0 0 640 480` without quotes.  Are the quotes optional or does this make any difference?

Comment: @Paolo Because when you use `$SizeAndPosition` (without quotes), the lack of quotes causes words to be splitted. Quoting `"$SizeAndPosition"` though wouldn't help either, because then the whole string would be a single argument. The best workaround is to use an array. Have a look at the link in my answer for a more detailed explanation

Comment: @Paolo [Field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) doesn't respect quoting, so `-win "0 0 640 480"` is split into five tokens `-win`, `"0`, `0`, `640`, and `480"`. The array trick is a good if bash-specific workaround. I suppose opening a subshell or fiddling with `IFS` would be another, if you're bound to POSIX. But perhaps it would be easiest to only store `0 0 640 480` in the variable and use `-win "$SizeAndPosition"` in the call.